# CPU fan always at 100% - MSI mobo, AMD CPU

Tags: motherboard, fan, cooling

The fan is always running at 100% (1800 RPM), even when the PC is idle (<5% usage) and temperatures are normal (<40C).

#### I've tried:

- Updated BIOS to latest version
- Installed AMD Overdrive, but the fan section is greyed out
- Set up fan profiles in SpeedFan but they have no effect (not sure if I did it correctly)
- Installed MSI Control Center, went to Green Power → Advanced → Mainboard, and set fan control down to 50% for CPU fan, but the speed goes back to 100% after reboot

#### Specs

- Mobo: MSI 760GM-P34
- Fan: Hyper 212 Evo (stock fan had same issue)
- CPU: AMD 4300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BIOS, open **H/W Monitor**

1. Enable **CPU Smart FAN Target**

   - I set it to 50C, but I think any value will do
2. Set **CPU Min FAN Speed** to 0%

   - I suppose anything <50% will work
3. Set **SYS FAN 1 Control** to 50%

   - seems irrelevant, but I set it just in case